# Getting Installed softwares name and version using "Reg Query"

Tags: registry

can anyone please help me to find out the display name and version of all installed softwares of a machine by using "Reg Query"?

if we use "/s" option with "reg query" then we will get all subkeys and value names recursively, but i need only display name and display version of each and every software. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exceute the below command
"REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s"

split the output of above command using "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" to get the array of strings. Now parse the each string for software display name and version.

Regular expressions for getting displayname and version are:

Displayname: "(.*)" + "DisplayName" + @"\s+REG_SZ\s+(.*)\s"

Displayversion: "(.*)" + "DisplayVersion" + @"\s+REG_SZ\s+(.*)\s"

Answer (score 1):

Its an old post but these commands can give you desired output. Both display name and version cannot be obtained at once but you can do one by one

```
Reg Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S /v DisplayName

Reg Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S /v DisplayVersion
```

other way around would be to combine the results with Find command to filter.

Comment: You can use use wildcard search to have all in one output 
Uninstall\ /S /v Display* 
And for x64 is better use registry path like this HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\